# How to test a working ConvNet in Python using Keras

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, keras

I am learning DL and I got to this site https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

I followed the examples and everything seems to be right, But now I want to test my own data, I mean I want to test my own images such as model.predict(mycat.jpg) and get the apropiate answer

The post I red does not have that information and somehow every book I got that makes examples of DL and CNN also forgets to tell how to use the network to check our own data after training.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you just finished fitting the data and want to see if cat.jpg returns a high probability for cat, below is some sampe code.

```
img = Image.open(path_to_cat)
img = np.expand_dims(np.array(img), 0)
img.reshape([1, height,width,channels])
prob = model.predict(img)
```

expand_dims is so that we have a batch index. You may also want to reshape the image to the shape of the input. In your case I believe it is [1, 3, 150, 150]. You can also predict on batches of images.

Edit: If test image isn't the same dimension as training images(150x150), putting this right after image.open will help

```
img = img.resize(np.divide(img.size,(scaling_amount).astype('int32')); img
```

That's uniform scaling and if that doesn't bring the image down to 150x150 exactly, use this after img.reshape

```
img = img[:,:150,:150]
```

What that does is cropping height and width to be 150. Check img.reshape and make sure its dimensions match training input dimensions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, Abusing your kindness, there is a tutorial or book you wouldlike to recomend to learn more?

Comment: Your answer actually gives me this error ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 47616768 into shape (0,150,150,3)

Comment: Oh, that's most likely because your image is not 150x150. Reshape command can't resize images, it only rearranges existing shape.

Comment: Francois Chollet's book is great. Fastai online course is also pretty good. The dimensions you want is 3 channels, 150 height, 150 width and 1 image.

Comment: Thanks for the information and the answer, the Fastai course seems great and I will be doing it.  as for your answer, the img = img[:,:150,:150] worked great, just one qesuint, how do I know 0 is cat and 1 is dog?

Comment: Check the labels in the training set and match it with the corresponding images.